# Bulk data insert in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have an .mdb file, which is used as a data storage by one particular application. The application itself does not have tools to insert large amounts of data, and I need to insert around 300-400 generated records.

How can this be accomplished without using VB? (since I know nothing about it)
At first I thought that writing a procedure, but from what I can tell Access does not support procedures and functions (which ir really weird), only basic SQL statements.

Is exporting data into other DB like Postgre, writing and running a procedure there, and importing the data back into .mdb file possible? Or there are other solutions?

Comment: Where is the data? Access will accept update data from excel, dbase, sql server, csv etc, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to export data from a specific table then select that table and right click on it.  A menu will appear that allows you to export the contents of that specific table.  Choose the format (probably .csv or .txt for max flexibility) and then import it whereever and manipulate it accordingly.

If you want to reimport your results then choose from the File -> Get External Data -> Import menu and import your newly manipulated data.  That should do it.  Just make sure that the data columns align properly with the table your importing into.  This shouldn't require any VBA.  This advice is pertinent to Access 2003.

Comment: Just tried exporting/importing, works fine, Excel might be enough for my case - the most complex variable field I need is dates of all days in particular date ranges excluding saturday and sunday.